# Помогите разобраться с запятыми

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите расставить запятые в данных примерах:

1. Я по совету друзей решил этим летом поехать в Сочи.
2. Иванов без разрешения соседей сделал перепланировку в своей квартире.
3. Стоит ли у машины без особых внешних дефектов менять кузов ?
4. Петров при возможности поехать на Канары уехал отдыхать в Сочи.
5. Почтальон с большой толстой сумкой на ремне постучался в дверь ко мне.
6. Куда я могу при наличии не очень большой суммы денег поехать отдыхать?

Answer (score 1):

Во всех примерах возможно факультативное обособление обстоятельственных оборотов, если у автора есть желание выделить их, особо подчеркнуть, акцентировать внимание на данной информации.

В то же время такое обособление не является обязательным, оборот может входить в основное сообщение и не обособляться.

Варианты с обособлением:

Я, по совету друзей, решил этим летом поехать в Сочи.

Иванов, без разрешения соседей, сделал перепланировку в своей квартире.

Стоит ли у машины, без особых внешних дефектов, менять кузов ?

Петров, при возможности поехать на Канары, уехал отдыхать в Сочи.

Почтальон, с большой толстой сумкой на ремне, постучался в дверь ко мне (предложение  имеет неестественную структуру). Возможный вариант: Почтальон, с большой толстой сумкой на ремне, постучался в мою дверь.

Куда я могу,  при наличии не очень большой суммы денег, поехать отдыхать?

Answer (score 0):

Стоит ли у машины без особых, внешних дефектов менять кузов ?

Answer (score 0):

См. Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в [Розенталь, § 20. Обособленные обстоятельства](http://www.web-lit.net/writer/9403/book/34923/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yazyiku_punktuatsiya/read/2).

> ... возможность обособления ставится в зависимость от степени распространенности оборота, его близости к основной части предложения, наличия добавочных оттенков значения, места по отношению к сказуемому, стилистической задачи и т. д., поэтому обособление *факультативно*.

Примеры:

> 1. Я, по совету друзей, решил этим летом поехать в Сочи.

Но

> Я решил этим летом поехать в Сочи по совету друзей.

Из [Розенталя](http://www.web-lit.net/writer/9403/book/34923/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yazyiku_punktuatsiya/read/2):

> Различие объясняется тем, что в конце предложения слова логически больше выделяются, и это затрудняет их «отрыв» от остальной части предложения.

Здесь тоже самое:

> 4. Петров, при возможности поехать на Канары, уехал отдыхать в Сочи.

Здесь, мне кажется, лучше не обособлять:

Цитата

> 2. Иванов без разрешения соседей сделал перепланировку в своей квартире.

и

> 6. Куда я могу при наличии не очень большой суммы денег поехать отдыхать?

Остальные примеры -- несогласованные определения.
См. [Розенталь, §92. Обособленные согласованные и несогласованные определения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm#%D0%B7_01)

> Несогласованные определения, выраженные косвенными падежами существительных (чаще с предлогом), в художественной речи обычно обособляются, если подчеркивается выражаемое ими значение...
>   В нейтральном стиле речи наблюдается устойчивая тенденция к отсутствию обособления таких определений...

Поэтому

> 3. Стоит ли у машины без особых внешних дефектов менять кузов ?

А это больше похоже на художественный текст:

> 5. Почтальон, с большой толстой сумкой на ремне, постучался в дверь ко мне.